# Objective-C garbage collection and C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, memory-management, garbage-collection, objective-c++

I'm writing a program in Objective-C with garbage collection enabled. It relies on a certain third party C++ library, but its headers don't compile as Objective-C++ so I have a good amount of pure C++ code with some Objective-C++ bridging the gap.

I did this sort of thing in the bridge, to allow passing Objective-C objects to C++:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
  @class NSManagedObjectID;
#else
  typedef void NSManagedObjectID;
#endif
```

My guess is that this is not the right thing to do, as C++ knows nothing of Objective-C's garbage collection. If the C++ side holds onto a reference (and I'd like it to) while nothing on the Objective-C side does, would I end up with a dangling pointer?

If so, what's the right way to deal with this?

Comment: More information is required, this is a fairly tricky area.

Comment: What details do you need? I left things intentionally vague, giving just what I thought was important.

Comment: Well, casting the ObjC objects to void* is relatively easy, but you can't cast an arbituary C++ object to a void* and still manage the object lifetime.

Comment: Sure you can - if you cast it back before you delete it. I'm able to do (basically) that here, I just don't know how to keep it from being  deleted in the meantime. Can I manually add and release references while GC is enabled?

Comment: Apple is very light on those details, but as long as the pointers still exist, then the GC should be able to see them - that said, I would be very surprised if the GC knew how to clean up the C++ object, so I would assume that they're not tracked at all.

Comment: Well, there's no C++ object to clean up - only (say) an NSManagedObjectID that C++ is holding onto temporarily before passing it back to Objective-C later. But I was under the impression that Objective-C used a compiler-assisted reference counting scheme, and didn't actually walk object trees at runtime. This would suggest that when a pointer is passed to C++ or C, there's no longer a reference as far as GC is concerned.

Comment: That depends on the scheme you use - if you're using GC, then no, reference counts are not being used, however, if you're using ARC instead (which has the compiler assist with reference counting), which Apple seems to be pushing, then yes, you will still need to ensure that reference counts are being set correctly on the C++ end.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm apparently not allowed to answer my own question yet, but it seems this is what I'm looking for: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects.operands.casts

Comment: That looks about right, however, do note that it's very misleading to call this "Garbage Collection", that refers to Apple's Garbage Collected mode, which is a real GC that does not use reference counts, at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when I said "garbage collection" I should really have said "automatic reference counting." And it seems that what I'm looking for are bridged casts ("These casts are required in order to transfer objects in and out of ARC control"):

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects.operands.casts